# Verb translation "ravage sexually"

Tags: traducción, verbos, solicitud-de-término

I'm looking for a verb or phrasal verb which is equivalent to the (slang) English *ravage* in the sexual sense, as in to engage in sex acts aggressively or with extreme physical desire.

For instance, would it make any sense to say:

> Él quiere *arrasarla* esta noche.

I've checked SpanishDict and Linguee but they only give the more literal sense.

Comment: What's the English sentence?

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean ravish rather than ravage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mi lo más cercano que se me ocurre sería la expresión "darle lo suyo"

> Él quiere **darle lo suyo** esta noche.

Quizá no tenga todas las connotaciones de *intensidad* y *agresividad* que tiene `ravage`, pero al igual que esta es el contexto lo que te da a entender que está siendo usada de manera coloquial. Es curioso que a diferencia de otros términos el uso no es un eufemismo para el sexo, si no que se sobreentiende que se refiere al sexo y se usa el término precisamente por tener ciertas connotaciones.

Siguiendo la misma regla podrías usa "dar para el pelo", que es algo que viene a significar "dar su merecido".

> Cuando llegue a casa con las notas, mi padre me va a dar para el pelo.

En el ámbito sexual "dar para el pelo" tendría esas connotaciones de agresividad e intensidad que buscas. Hay otras expresiones para el sexo (no me refiero solo a *follar*, *joder*, etc. Poner a alguien "mirando a Cuenca" es otra forma de referirse al acto sexual, pero no creo que necesariamente implique esa intensidad física que buscas.

> Él quiere **ponerla mirando a Cuenca** esta noche.

Podrías decir que

> Él quiere **matarla a polvos** esta noche.

Que es más "física y agresiva" como pide la pregunta, pero también una expresión un poco chabacana.

Por último (casi a modo de anécdota), creo que la expresión más "salvaje" que yo he oído nunca usar a alguien sobre el tema fue un

> La va a dejar *albina*

Answer (score 3):

The only verb that comes to mind right now is, in my dialect (West Spain), is *empotrar*, that literally means *to embed* but also to hit something with full force. For example, *quiero empotrarla* (if said by a man) or *quiero que me empotre* (if said by a woman).

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! I suggest improving your answer by making clear what _empotrar_ literally is, you can cite [its third definition from the dictionary](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EsavzrZ) which will make clear where the sexual meaning comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would start by double-checking the definitions of the English word *ravage*, to make sure I have the idea clear in my mind, before looking for an equivalent expression in Spanish.  But I ran into a problem: I couldn't find a definition remotely matching "engage in sex acts aggressively" or "engage in sex acts with extreme physical desire."  However, I'm aware that romance novels do use the word that way, and in the Urban Dictionary at least one opinion backs up these meanings.

So I will set aside "ravage" and go back to your definitions.

"Engage in sex acts aggressively" --> *violar*

"Engage in sex acts with extreme physical desire" --> *tener relaciones sexuales con deseo intenso o desesperado*

(Of course, there are more vulgar ways of expressing "tener relaciones sexuales," which could be combined with *deseo intenso*.)

Comment: I suspect that this question is based on a mis-hearing of ravage and ravish which sound very similar in many dialects of English although the OP does state it is slang. Your suggestion of _violar_ seems to me to be an appropriate translation these days.