# ¿Cuáles expresiones eufemísticas se usan para el acto sexual?

Tags: eufemismos, sexualidad

En inglés, se usan muchas expresiones idiomáticas o eufemísticas para el acto sexual.

Por ejemplo, podemos decir:

- To sleep with... (dormir con...)
- To be with... (estar con...)
- To do it with... (hacerlo con...)
- To do... (hacer a...) *Shakespeare la usó.*
- To make love to... (hacer amor a...)

¿Cuáles expresiones idiomáticas o eufemísticas se usan en español?

Comment: Hay muchas! Un poco genérica la pregunta... Puede servirte [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/1674)

Comment: Y no olvidemos *hacer el amor*, *penetración* y *el coito* (intercourse).

Comment: creo que esto debería convertirse en una pregunta y respuesta de la comunidad.... no por lo util si no por lo extenso y cambiante de la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few examples from previous questions:

- Follar:  [¿Cuándo y cómo adquirió la palabra “follar” su acepción sexual?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23944/5481),
- Poner mirando a Cuenca: [Origen de la expresión “poner mirando a Cuenca”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22583/5481)
- Echar un polvo: [¿De dónde viene la expresión “echar un polvo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32084/5481)
- Dar fuerte (in very especific context): explained in [What does “me quiso dar fuerte” mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31046/5481)
- Darle a alguien lo suyo / empotrar : from [Verb translation “ravage sexually”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20639/5481),
- Coger (in certain countries): explained in [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481)
- Checar el aceite: [Significado como jerga de “checar el aceite”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25576/5481)

Comment: Nota: muchas de estas expresiones no sin eufemismos, sino otras maneras coloquiales de referirse al acto sexual

Answer (score 2):

Como en todas las lenguas, hay muchas y depende del lugar. En España, se puede decir

- acostarse con
- hacer el amor con
- tener sexo con

La expresión coloquial más común es "follar" . "Hacerlo con" también se dice algunas veces.

Comment: Tirarse, echar un polvo, hacerse...

Comment: no creo que "hacer el amor con" y menos "tener sexo con" sean formas eufemisitcas. Vamos, mas claro no lo pueden decir.

Comment: "Follar" ¿no se localiza en España?

Answer (score 2):

En Chile la forma más común es "**tener relaciones**". Yo opino que es ridículamente eufemística.

Answer (score 1):

In South America is quite usual to hear references to the sexual act —euphemistically so— as:

> hacer el amor

---

> tener relaciones

---

> acostarse / encamarse

---

> tener un affaire

---

> tener un [encuentro cercano del tercer tipo](https://www.sopitas.com/mientras-tanto/expectativa-vs-realidad-del-dia-de-san-valentin/)

---

And, this one below, outdated but funny {a saying I heard  my mother, who is 76)

> tener un "desliz"
>
> *la fulana tuvo un desliz con un Don Juan* [the "Don Juan" means a generic for a serial-seducer]

Where desliz means a mistake, a slip,  a slide away from moral rules, specially in reference to sexual relationships

> **[desliz](https://dle.rae.es/desliz)**
>
> 2. m. Desacierto, indiscreción involuntaria, flaqueza en sentido moral, con especial referencia a las relaciones sexuales.